# Access an object created in another class from a KeyListener

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

I am trying to figure out how to change a field of an object that was created in my main class from a keylistener class.  I have made a class called KeyMaster and all it does is listen for keyboard input through an eventqueue that was created in the main class.  I want to be able to change the x and y coordinates through the KeyMaster class when I push up, left, down, right whatever.  The problem is i cannot get to the Ship object from the KeyListener class.  Please help.  :)

```
public class TheMage extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {               
        TheMage Main = new TheMage();
        Player Ship = new Player(50,50);

        KeyMaster KeyEvnt = new KeyMaster();        

        EventQueue.invokeLater
        (new Runnable() 
            {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                Main.addKeyListener(KeyEvnt);
                Main.setFocusable(true);
                Main.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );      
    }
}


public class Player {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class KeyMaster implements KeyListener {

    public KeyMaster() {

    }    

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println("Hello - Type");        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println("Hello - Press");        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        System.out.println("Hello - Rel");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Player` field in the `KeyMaster` class and inject the current player into the field through the constructor:

```
private Player player;
KeyMaster(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}
```

Then in the `main` method you can create the `KeyMaster` as follows:

```
KeyMaster KeyEvnt = new KeyMaster(Ship);
```